# Show div on radio button check using JS fallback

Tags: javascript, css, forms, radio-button, fallback

I am building a website of which the desktop version displays 10 images all at once (5x2), which obviously doesn't look too good on a small smartphone display. In order to conquer this problem, I made 10 radio buttons (which only display on the mobile version of the website) and only show the image that accompanies the checked radio button. This was very easy to implement with HTML and CSS3 like this:

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name='pdr' id="pdr1"><label for="pdr1"> Click here</label>
<div class="populardevice" id="populardevice1">stuff in this div</div>
```

CSS:

```
.populardevice {
  display: none;
}
input#pdr1:checked ~ #populardevice1 {
  display: inline;
}
```

The problem is that older browsers don't support the :checked selector. My idea was to use the CSS3 way of displaying the div if it's supported, and use JavaScript as a fallback if not. I already found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514760/javascript-show-hide-div-when-radio-button-checked), which is basically what I want. The only problem is how do I detect if support for the :checked selector is present? I was thinking of Modernizr but it seems like all that would do is create an additional class in my CSS that says no-checked (right?), which would be of no use to me since I want to run a piecie of JS in that case. Or would Modernizr be fit for this case, utilizing it something like this (pseudo-code - I have no idea how to write this yet but if it's the solution, I will find out how):

```
if (Modernizr.:checked supported) {
  use that and terminate this function;
} else {
  Execute the JavaScript function from the link above;
}
```

Or do you guys advise me to implement something completely different?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wouldn't make it too hard for yourself and just tackle this problem using JavaScript, it's a small piece of code which would not influence the overal performance of your site. Let me know if you want to see an answer for this. But, first consider if using radio buttons to show an image (on mobile screens) is a good solution... why do you want to do this? Is it because there are too many images? Then simple hide some on mobile screens.

Comment: I know it doesn't impact site performance, but I want to use as little Javascript so that people who have it disabled can still view the site in the correct way (if your browser doesn't support CSS3 or JS, you're screwed(ish) - but that's a situation that almost never occurs). I want to offer mobile users a page on which they have to do little to no scrolling, but I will still need to show the images if required.

Comment: What is wrong with showing 10 images on a mobile screen? Are they too big? Are there too many images shown? If you ask yourself this question, you get to the real problem. Otherwise your question would be: "How to check if a CSS feature is supported using Modernizr?". Schlaus already pointed you in the right direction for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Modernizr website](https://modernizr.com/docs/#what-is-modernizr):

> Using Modernizr with JavaScript
>
> The Modernizr object
>
> Modernizr keeps track of the results of all of it's feature detections
>   via the Modernizr object. That means that for each test, a
>   corresponding property will be added. You just have to test for
>   truthiness in your code to figure out what you want to do
>
> ```
> if (Modernizr.awesomeNewFeature) {
>   showOffAwesomeNewFeature();
> } else {
>   getTheOldLameExperience();
> }
> ```

So your pseudo code was pretty close!

Comment: I actually already visited that page multiple times, but I don't think I understood it correctly until now. Modernizr can do feature detection and based on that either: a. create a no-support class in the CSS or b. execute a piece of JS, right? In which case I just need to add the JS show div function inside the else statement.

Comment: Apparently this is the case.